# How to check if a variable is defined?

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

In AS3, we say if a!= undefined , but how to that check in haxe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it against `null`

http://haxelearning.wikispaces.com/Data+Types+and+Variables#x-Data Types In Haxe--Unknown

Answer (score 3):

This guide could be useful for you.
http://www.openfl.org/archive/developer/documentation/actionscript-developers/